# CodeMirror document.getElementById("textarea-id") блокирует получение value поля текста

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea, codemirror

Есть textarea id="textarea-id". Используется текстовый редактор CodeMirror. Для его активации используется такое обращение:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("textarea-id"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  mode: "application/x-httpd-php",
  indentUnit: 4,
  theme: "base16-light",
  indentWithTabs: true,
  styleActiveLine: true,
  lineWrapping: true, 
  tabSize: 4
});
```

Далее состав этого textarea необходимо вывести, но оно не видит изменений

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  alert($("textarea").val());
});
```

и просто выводит пустую строку. 
Пробовал вырезать подключение CodeMirror, сразу помогло, но без него никак. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(
  document.getElementById("textarea-id"), {
    ...
});

editor .on("change", function(cm) {
  $("#textarea-id").val(cm.getValue());
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
  console.log($('#textarea-id').val());
});
```